# Return movies with their ranks based on country

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a list of movies, each movie has a ranking for different countries. Also I have rankings from different days. For example:

**Movie Name:** Ready Player One

**Rankings:** USA #4 04/02/2018 - Canada #32 04/02/2018 - USA #8 03/02/2018 - Canada #30 03/02/2018

**Movie Name:** Deadpool

**Rankings:** USA #3 03/01/2016 - Canada #23 03/01/2016 - USA #2 02/01/2016 - Canada #20 02/01/2016

What I'm trying to do is to return the movies with their rankings sorted based on countries. For example (returned object):

```
{
    name: Ready Player One, 
    rankings: [{usa: [{~rankings~}, {~rankings~}]}, {canada: [{~rankings~}]}]
}
```

I've created the following tables: [image: https://i.imgur.com/Lh9Lv6h.png]

I'm not sure if I did the the correct relationships and tables. I did some queries without result.